# Stopping executing of SQL scripts after error occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file

I am executing multiple SQL scripts using batch file but now I want to stop execution of batch file if error occurs in any one of the scripts.

This is my batch file:

```
sqlcmd -S dbdev026b\dbdev026b -i c:Test1.sql -o c:\o1.txt
sqlcmd -S dbdev026b\dbdev026b -i c:Test2.sql -o c:\o2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcmd -S dbdev026b\dbdev026b -i c:Test1.sql -o c:\o1.txt || exit /b 1
sqlcmd -S dbdev026b\dbdev026b -i c:Test2.sql -o c:\o2.txt || exit /b 2
```